# Keep nan in result when perform statsmodels OLS regression in python

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I want to perform OLS regression using python's statsmodels package. But my dataset has nans in it. Currently, I know I can use missing='drop' option when perform OLS regression but some of the results (fitted value or residuals) will have different lengths as the original y variable.

I have the following code as an example:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

yvars = np.array([1.0, 6.0, 3.0, 2.0, 8.0, 4.0, 5.0, 2.0, np.nan, 3.0])
xvars = np.array(
    [
        [1.0, 8.0],
        [8.0, np.nan],
        [np.nan, 3.0],
        [3.0, 6.0],
        [5.0, 3.0],
        [2.0, 7.0],
        [1.0, 3.0],
        [2.0, 2.0],
        [7.0, 9.0],
        [3.0, 1.0],
    ]
)

res = sm.OLS(yvar, sm.add_constant(xvars), missing='drop').fit()
res.resid
```

The result is as follows:

```
array([-0.71907958, -1.9012464 ,  1.78811122,  1.18983701,  2.63854267,
       -1.45254075, -1.54362416])
```

My question is that the result is an array has length 7 (after dropping nans), but the length of yvar is 10. So, what if I want to return the residual of the same length as yvar and just output nan in whatever position where there are at least 1 nan in either yvar or xvars?

Basically, the result I want to get is:

```
array([-0.71907958, nan , nan , -1.9012464 ,  1.78811122,  1.18983701,  2.63854267,
       -1.45254075, nan , -1.54362416])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's too difficult to implement in statsmodels. So users need to handle it themselves.

The results attributes like fittedvalues and resid are for the actual sample used.

The `predict` method of the results instance preserves nans in the provided predict data `exog` array, but other methods and attributes do not.
`results.predict(xvars_all)`

One workaround:

Use a pandas DataFrame for the data.
Then, AFAIR, `resid` and `fittedvalues` of the results instance are pandas Series with the appropriate index.
This can then be used to add those to the original index or DataFrame.
That's what the `predict` method does.